# How to combine CSV files, whose names contain words from two dicts?

Tags: python

#### I have a folder containing multiple files:

```
files = ['apple29c9_michigan_1995.csv',
         'apple30c7_rome_1995.csv',
         'apple67c5_melba_1995.csv',
         'apple12c2_rome_2010.csv',
         'mango76c6_southern_blush_1995.csv',
         'mango76c6_southern_1995.csv',
         'mango76c6_blush_1995.csv',
         'mango65c2_southern_blush_2020.csv',
         'mango34c4_keitt_1995.csv',
         'mango22c5_kent_1995.csv',
         'mango76c6_southern_blush_sweet_1995.csv',
         'mango76c6_sweet_southern_blush_1995.csv']
```

#### I have two dictionaries and a variable(year of manufacture) as:

```
d1 = {'Filename': ['apple','mango']}
d2 = {'Filetype': ['rome', 'melba', 'southern_blush', 'kent']}
yr = 1995
```

#### How can I:

1. Select all files from the folder, where the file name contains:

   - either `Filename`, `'apple'` or `'mango'`
   - AND any `Filetype`, `'rome'`, `'melba'`, `'southern_blush'`, or `'kent'`

     - must be an exact match (e.g. `sweet_southern_blush` is not equal to `southern_blush`)
   - AND `yr`, as 1995
2. Append the files belonging to each filename together.

   - one file for apple, that would have `apple30c7_rome_1995.csv`  and `apple67c5_melba_1995.csv` appended
   - similarly, one file for the mango files.

#### Output should be:

```
apple30c7_rome_1995.csv
apple67c5_melba_1995.csv >> Appended into one file


mango76c6_southern_blush_1995.csv
mango22c5_kent_1995.csv >> Appeneded into one file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module to get all files

   - This module offers classes representing filesystem paths with semantics appropriate for different operating systems.
   - Use [`.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) to find the files with the specified pattern
   - Use [`.stem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem) to extract only the filename for use in the conditional

     - `WindowsPath('E:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/apple30c7_rome_1995.csv').stem` is `apple30c7_rome_1995`, for example.
2. Create the combinations, `combos`, of terms, beforehand.
3. Iterate through the files, and add a file to the `dict`, `files_to_combine`, when it passes the conditional.

   - `f_name` is split into a list at `_`

     - `fn = f_name[0]` is always the `Filename` component, so it must contain `n`, therefore `n in fn`
     - `y = f_name[-1]` is always the year, so it must equal `yr`, therefore `yr == y`
     - `ft = f_name[1:-1]` is the `Filetype` component, so it must be an exact match to any of the values in `t`
   - For the generator `any(v == ft for v in t)`

     - From the `for-loop`, `t` is `['rome', 'melba', 'southern_blush', 'kent']` and `v` iterates through each value of `t`.
     - `v == ft` creates a Boolean `True` or `False` if `v` is `ft` or not.
     - `any` returns `True` if any of the Booleans in the generator are `True`.
     - To change between an exact `str` match, or containing a `str`, choose `==` or `in`, respectively.
4. Use [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to read, combine, and write to a csv file.

   - For this example, two files are created, `apple_1995.csv` and `mango_1995.csv`.

```py
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from collections import defaultdict as dd


yr = str(yr)  # convert year to a str
combos = [[n] + [d2['Filetype']] for n in d1['Filename']]  # list of unique combination

# find files in specified path
files = Path('c:/path_to_files').glob('*.csv')

# group matching combos in a dict
files_to_combine = dd(list)
for file in files:
    f_name = file.stem.split('_')  # get the file name and split it into a list
    y = f_name[-1]  # year
    fn = f_name[0]  # filename string
    ft = '_'.join(f_name[1:-1])  # filetype string
    for (n, t) in combos:  # iterate through each list in combos
        if (n in fn) and (yr == y) and any(v == ft for v in t):  # check the conditionals
            
            files_to_combine[f'{n}_{yr}'].append(file)  # add to the appropriate dict key
            
# combine csv groups into one group
for k, v in files_to_combine.items():
    df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in v])
    df.to_csv(f'{k}.csv', index=False)
```

### `combos`

```py
[['apple', ['rome', 'melba', 'southern_blush', 'kent']],
 ['mango', ['rome', 'melba', 'southern_blush', 'kent']]]
```

### `files_to_combine`

```py
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'apple_1995': [WindowsPath('apple30c7_rome_1995.csv'),
                            WindowsPath('apple67c5_melba_1995.csv')],
             'mango_1995': [WindowsPath('mango76c6_southern_blush_1995.csv'),
                            WindowsPath('mango22c5_kent_1995.csv')]})
```